# "Ignore" a file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to modify a batch code from https://code.google.com/p/protoc-gen-docbook/

Inside this batch file these is a `FOR` loop that checks if the files in the folder ends with .proto (which they do). So it will then run all these proto files and print the content in a pdf file.

My issue here is that I want the batch script to ignore X.proto because its content is not important. I don't want it to be removed from the folder since Y.proto uses stuff from X.proto, and if I do remove X.proto my batch won't work since it won't find the X.proto file.

So I was wondering if there is any possibility to ignore a certain file but still be able to copy all content from Y.proto and Z.proto? If yes, how do I write it in batch script?

This is how the `FOR` loop looks like:

```
for /R . %%f in (*.proto) do (
set B=%%f
call :concat_files !B:%CD%\=!
)
::echo proto_files = %proto_files%
```

I've tried toying around a bit by adding an `IF` statement before the `SET`:

```
IF NOT "%%~nf"=="descriptor.proto" echo %%~nf
```

Another way I have been thinking is to do something like this inside the `FOR` loop:

```
(*proto && !X.proto) <--(something like take all protos and/but not X.proto).
```

So if there is any possibilities to ignore or do an "expect" (like database: do all of this expect that), I would be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IF` command to skip the x.proto file:

```
FOR /R . %%f IN (*.proto) DO (
    IF NOT "%%~nf"=="x" (
        REM Do your stuff here
    )
)
```

The command `IF NOT "%%~nf"=="x"` will compare the file name only (without the extension) with `x`, and will execute the code block only if the name doesn't match. You do not need to compare the extention since you are including only `*.proto` files in the `FOR` filter.

Comment: Thank you i managed to fix it with some testing here and there, this is how the for-loop looks like now.

`for /R . %%f in (*.proto) do ( 
IF NOT "%%~nf"=="descriptor" (
set B=%%f
call :concat_files !B:%CD%\=!
)
)
::echo proto_files = %proto_files%`